Why is the c++ date library trying to access my Downloads folder when I call current_zone()?
In the date library by Howard Hinnant that's been added to the c++ standard library, the first I call current_zone(), which is the equivalent of std::chrono::current_zone() in C++20. It tries to get the get the tzdb_list, it is a static variable that's lazily initialised:
static tzdb_list tz_db = create_tzdb();

Inside create_tzdb() there is:
const std::string install = get_install();

And inside that there is:
#if !USE_OS_TZDB

static std::string& access_install()
{
     static std::string install
#ifndef INSTALL

            = get_download_folder() + folder_delimiter + "tzdata";

#else   // !INSTALL

}

Then it assigns "C:\Users\MyComputer\Downloads\tzdata\" to a variable. It checks if that filepath exists, and it doesn't, and throws an error:
if (!file_exists(install))
{
    std::string msg = "Timezone database not found at \"";
    msg += install;
    msg += "\"";
    throw std::runtime_error(msg);
}

Why is it getting my download folder? When I call current_zone(). Why does it need to download anything in this case? I don't know what a timezone database is, I thought this stuff resided on the OS.

Is the code you're showing from your program, or from some implementation of the standard library? If from the standard library, then which implementation (GCC, Clang, MSVC, etc) and version? Or from some other library (then which version of it)?

And I feel that the #if !USE_OS_TZDB part might be relevant.

@Someprogrammerdude It's the code found on Github, made by Howard Hinnant, which is what was (I believe) incorporated into the standard library. The reason I did this is because I've had trouble compiling C++20 on some compilers. Yes, I have a feeling #if !USE_OS_TZDB has to do with it, but I don't know what a timezone database is and I'd like to know what's happening here.

Time zone data is governed by an international standardization organization and updated unpredictably, in accordance with geopolitical borders and local time policy. Therefore the system always needs to download the latest version before continuing to format the datetime.

Howard Hinnant is the reference for std datetime implementation. Not every implementation of std datetime copies his, but the interface of std is borrowed from Hinnant's job.

Some nitpicking: The code you show might want to access a file in the "downloads" directory, but it doesn't actually download anything.

FYI, the MSVC tools have implemented this library within  under the /std:c++20 option.  I recommend using that over my date lib if at all possible.

Timezones for a country are defined by the government of that country. E.g. there are countries that set the dates that daylight savings will start and end by legislation each year.
A timezone database is a record of all of that information, and in some contexts it will need to be frequently updated. Ordinarily it would be dealt with by the OS, but you are looking at code guarded by #if !USE_OS_TZDB, i.e. you have opted-out of using the OS timezone database.

Hmm, when I use the std::chrono version it doesn't throw an error, is that because the standard library std::chrono has this flag set? It's on by default in the Github repo, ie., it tries to download it it seems.

@Zebrafish each implementation of the standard library will have implemented this in their own way, they won't necessarily have used Howard's version.

I define #define USE_OS_TZDB 1 and now it tries to include <dirent.h> which is supposedly only found on Linux. I'm on Windows. Was this intended?

Oh wow! error "USE_OS_TZDB can not be used on Windows" ... interesting.

Right.  Linux and MacOS (and other Apple OS's) ship with the IANA database.  Windows does not.  However this lib can be configured to work with a pre-downloaded copy on Windows as opposed to doing that automatically.  See https://howardhinnant.github.io/date/tz.html#Installation for more details.
